# The Difference between "Imperium Persarum" and "Persarum Imperium"

Tags: latin, word-order

First time asking. :)

As the title suggests, I wanted to know the difference between the two names for the *Persian Empire* in Latin. (I'm not even sure if both are used...)

I've tried asking other people before coming here, but I never got a clear answer.

Thank you!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar#Word_order) about Latin: *Adjectives and participles usually directly followed nouns, unless they were adjectives of beauty, size, quantity, goodness, or truth, in which case they preceded the noun being modified.*

Comment: @bytebuster. It is incredible how much rubbish you can read in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

There is only stylistic difference. Attributes in Latin can precede or follow the head noun so both are well-formed and have the same meaning.